# Why is a vector used while defining priority queue of structures?

Tags: c++

I know that we can define a priority queue of structures in the following way -

```
std::priority_queue<somestructure, vector<somestructure>, compare> pq;
```

Where compare is the structure which contains the compare function. I want to ask why we need to use vector as the second argument in this declaration. How is a vector related to a priority queue while defining the above priority queue?

Comment: Did you check out the [class documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)?

Comment: A `std::priority_queue` isn't a container itself, it's a container *adapter*. It *uses* a container internally to store the queue. By default it uses `std::deque`, but any container satisfying the requirements will work, like for example `std::vector`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Make this an answer please...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, the default underlying container for `std::priority_queue` is `std::vector` not `std::deque` according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue.

Comment: @Karmo It *used* to be `std::deque`, I don't know in which standard it was changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::priority_queue` is what we call a container **adapter**. As you know in C++ we got containers like `std::vector`, `std:array` or `std::deque`. All those are there to directly save stuff of type `T` into them, with different pros and cons.

`std::stack` for example is a container adapter, which can be used on top of `std:deque`. The only thing this adapter does is to take away the functionality of `std::deque` to insert at the end, or take from the end. By this the user is forced to use the `std::deque` only like a stack.

Something similiar is true for `std::priority_queue`, it forces you to only insert into the underlying container, a `std::vector` for example, in an order. By this you get some nice properties of how to find elements in this container. In this special case, by taking more effort into how to insert new elements in the underlying container, and taking away the freedom to randomly insert an element anywhere you like. So you got O(log(n)) complexity for the **insert** instead of O(1) (instead of inserting at the end for example). But by that you have a complexity of only O(1) to **find** the largest element, instead of O(n).

There is nothing special about `std::vector` in this case, you could use **any container that satisfy the needs of this container adaptor**, you could also use `std::deque` or your own container or [to quote](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

> The type of the underlying container to use to store the elements.
>   The container must satisfy the requirements of SequenceContainer, and
>   its iterators must satisfy the requirements of
>   LegacyRandomAccessIterator. Additionally, it must provide the
>   following functions with the usual semantics: front() push_back()
>   pop_back() The standard containers std::vector and std::deque satisfy
>   these requirements.

Comment: Awesome answer.

Comment: I would note that there are other considerations on whether to use a backing `std::vector` or `std:deque` container. 

The priority queue uses the `pop_back` method of the backing container to remove items from its `pop` method. The `pop_back` differs for `std::vector` (doesn't change capacity) vs for `std::deque`.

Comment: std::deque won't change it capacity because of pop_back either or to quote C++20: void pop_back();
Effects: An erase operation that erases the last element of a deque invalidates only the past-the-end iterator and all iterators and references to the erased elements. An erase operation that erases the first element of a deque but not the last element invalidates only iterators and references to the erased elements. ... [Note: pop_front and pop_back are erase operations. —end note]

Comment: @Superlokkus how does that mean it won't change its capacity? Deque is a doubly linked list, thus it makes sense for any insertion/deletion from the container no iterators except erased elements are invalidated. But that does not mean the capacity has to stay the same.

Comment: @Quest `std::deque`is NOT a doubly linked list. `std::list` usally is a doubly linked list. While `std::deque` is more like `std::vector` but a bit more flexible, or to quote cpp reference: "Typical implementations use a sequence of individually allocated fixed-size arrays, with additional bookkeeping". Also `std::deque` has some invalidation and complexity guarantees when popping at its ends, so its very likely that as in the `std::vector` case, it won't change its capacity.